# How do you loop over files containing A and B in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep, text-manipulation

I'm looking for all the files in a directory that contain "AAA" **and** "BBB".
I then want to modify/do stuff with each of the found files. The file names do contain spaces.

`grep` piping to `grep` would seem simple but requires the `xargs` to function correctly.

The multiple match functionality in `grep` (from what I can tell) is only for "AAA" **or** "BBB".

What I've got is:

```sh
for FILENAME in "$(grep -ilrZ "AAA" ./files/* | xargs -0 grep -ilr "BBB")"
do
  echo "$FILENAME"
  echo "match"
done
```

However, this treats the list as files (including the newlines) as a single entity (i.e. "match" will only print once).

Removing the double quotes from the `for` sub-shell means every space is a new thing to be looped over, which breaks up filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `grep -Z` in the first invocation is a solution to the problem in the second case, too.

```
grep -ilrZ "AAA" ./files/* |
xargs -r0 grep -Zil "BBB" |
xargs -r0 -i echo "{} match"
```

Using `-r` in the second `grep` makes no sense because you only want to examine precisely the files from the output of the first `grep`.

If you just want to list the files, of course, just `grep -l` already does that; presumably, you will want to do something more complex in the second `xargs`.

An alternative solution might be

```
find ./files -type f \
    -exec grep -qi "AAA" {} \; \
    -exec grep -qi "BBB" {} \; \
    -exec sh -c 'for f; do echo "$f matched"; done' _ {} +
```

The way this works is, if one `-exec` fails, the file for which it failed will be regarded as a failed predicate by `find`, and so the remainder of the predicates will be skipped. The files which reach the final predicate will have returned success from all the previous predicates.

The latter should work on non-Linux platforms which lack the GNU extensions `grep -Z`, `xargs -0` etc.

In case it's not obvious, `find` and `grep -r` examine subdirectories, too. If you just want to examine the current directory, omitting the `-r` from the first `grep` should work. For `find`, you can add `-maxdepth 1` before `-type f` to only examine the current directory.

Demo: https://ideone.com/ELqKxZ

For much more on this topic, see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 and perhaps https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 1):

@tripleee has an excellent, robust answer. An alternate take. Assuming your shell is bash and your awk is GNU awk

```sh
shopt -s globstar    # enable recursive globbing with **
gawk '
    BEGINFILE {a = b = 0}
    /AAA/ {a = 1}
    /BBB/ {b = 1}
    a && b {print FILENAME; nextfile}
' ./files/** 2>/dev/null
```